# Some confused regarding to Rust memory order

Tags: rust, memory-barriers

I have some questions regarding to Rust memory barrier, let's have a look about this [example](https://riptutorial.com/rust/example/21259/atomics-and-memory-ordering), based on the example, I made some changes:

```rust
use std::cell::UnsafeCell;
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicUsize, Ordering};
use std::sync::{Arc, Barrier};
use std::thread;

struct UsizePair {
    atom: AtomicUsize,
    norm: UnsafeCell<usize>,
}

// UnsafeCell is not thread-safe. So manually mark our UsizePair to be Sync.
// (Effectively telling the compiler "I'll take care of it!")
unsafe impl Sync for UsizePair {}

static NTHREADS: usize = 8;
static NITERS: usize = 1000000;

fn main() {
    let upair = Arc::new(UsizePair::new(0));

    // Barrier is a counter-like synchronization structure (not to be confused
    // with a memory barrier). It blocks on a `wait` call until a fixed number
    // of `wait` calls are made from various threads (like waiting for all
    // players to get to the starting line before firing the starter pistol).
    let barrier = Arc::new(Barrier::new(NTHREADS + 1));

    let mut children = vec![];

    for _ in 0..NTHREADS {
        let upair = upair.clone();
        let barrier = barrier.clone();
        children.push(thread::spawn(move || {
            barrier.wait();

            let mut v = 0;
            while v < NITERS - 1 {
                // Read both members `atom` and `norm`, and check whether `atom`
                // contains a newer value than `norm`. See `UsizePair` impl for
                // details.
                let (atom, norm) = upair.get();
                if atom != norm {
                    // If `Acquire`-`Release` ordering is used in `get` and
                    // `set`, then this statement will never be reached.
                    println!("Reordered! {} != {}", atom, norm);
                }
                v = atom;
            }
        }));
    }

    barrier.wait();

    for v in 1..NITERS {
        // Update both members `atom` and `norm` to value `v`. See the impl for
        // details.
        upair.set(v);
    }

    for child in children {
        let _ = child.join();
    }
}

impl UsizePair {
    pub fn new(v: usize) -> UsizePair {
        UsizePair {
            atom: AtomicUsize::new(v),
            norm: UnsafeCell::new(v),
        }
    }

    pub fn get(&self) -> (usize, usize) {
        let atom = self.atom.load(Ordering::Acquire); //Ordering::Acquire

        // If the above load operation is performed with `Acquire` ordering,
        // then all writes before the corresponding `Release` store is
        // guaranteed to be visible below.

        let norm = unsafe { *self.norm.get() };
        (atom, norm)
    }

    pub fn set(&self, v: usize) {
        unsafe { *self.norm.get() = v };

        // If the below store operation is performed with `Release` ordering,
        // then the write to `norm` above is guaranteed to be visible to all
        // threads that "loads `atom` with `Acquire` ordering and sees the same
        // value that was stored below". However, no guarantees are provided as
        // to when other readers will witness the below store, and consequently
        // the above write. On the other hand, there is also no guarantee that
        // these two values will be in sync for readers. Even if another thread
        // sees the same value that was stored below, it may actually see a
        // "later" value in `norm` than what was written above. That is, there
        // is no restriction on visibility into the future.

        self.atom.store(v, Ordering::Release); //Ordering::Release
    }
}
```

Basically, I just changed the judge condition into `if atom != norm` and the memory order in `get` and `set` method.

According to what I have learned so far, all the memory operations(1. doesn't require that these memory operations are operating on the same memory location, 2. no matter it is an atomic operation or normal memory operation) happens before a `store Release`, will be visible to the memory operation after a `load Acquire`.

I don't get why `if atom != norm` is not always true? Actually, from the comments in the [example](https://riptutorial.com/rust/example/21259/atomics-and-memory-ordering), it does point out that:

> However, no guarantees are provided as to when other readers will witness the below store, and consequently the above write. On the other hand, there is also no guarantee that these two values will be in sync for readers. Even if another thread sees the same value that was stored below, it may actually see a "later" value in `norm` than what was written above. That is, there is no restriction on visibility into the future.

Can someone explain to me why `norm` can see some "future value"?

Also in [this c++ example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_thread_fence), is it the same reason that causes these statements in code?

> v0, v1, v2 might turn out to be -1, some, or all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> all the memory operations ... happens before a store Release, will be visible to the memory operation after a load Acquire.

**That's true only if the acquire load sees the value from the release store.**

If not, the acquire load ran before the release store was globally visible, so there are no guarantees about anything; you didn't actually synchronize with that writer.  The load of `norm` happens after the acquire load, so another store might have become globally visible<sup>1</sup> during that interval.

Also, the `norm` store is done first<sup>2</sup> so even if `atom` and `norm` were loaded simultaneously (e.g. by one wide atomic load), it would still be possible for it to see `norm` updated by `atom` not yet.

**Footnote 1**:  (Or visible to this thread, on the rare machine where that can happen without being *globally* visible, e.g. PowerPC)

**Footnote 2**: The only actual guarantee is not-later; they could both become globally visible as one wider transaction, e.g. the compiler would be allowed to merge the `norm` store and the `atom` store into one wider atomic store, or hardware could do that via store coalescing in the store buffer.  So there might never be a time interval when you could observe `norm` updated by `atom` not; it depends on the implementation (hardware and compiler).

(IDK what kind of guarantees Rust gives here or how it formally defines synchronization and memory order.  But the basics of acquire and release synchronization are fairly universal.  https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/.  In C++ reading a non-atomic `norm` at all without achieving synchronization would be data-race UB (undefined behaviour), but of course when compiled for real hardware the effects I describe are what would happen in practice, whether the source language is C++ or Rust.)

Comment: Great answer, thank you so much! I have another question then, 
```
pub fn is_empty(&self) -> bool {
        let head = self.head.load(Ordering::SeqCst);
        let tail = self.tail.load(Ordering::SeqCst);
        tail == head}
```
can we make sure that, head always loads before tail?

Comment: @PoppinDouble: yes, or at least "not later than".  SeqCst already does that; so would just making the first load an acquire load.  https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/.  Within one thread, all operations in program order after an Acquire are ordered after it for memory order as well.  That's the whole point of acquire.

Comment: just want to confirm that, all the memory fences, are apply to ALL the instructions before and after it, not only just the adjacent two instructions, right?

Comment: @PoppinDouble: Yes, of course.  (Note that an acquire operation (such as a load) isn't technically a "fence".  It's a one-way barrier, unlike C++ `atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_acquire)` [which is a 2-way barrier](https://preshing.com/20131125/acquire-and-release-fences-dont-work-the-way-youd-expect/).)  But yes, acquire operations are ordered wrt. all other operations in the same thread, otherwise they'd be nearly useless.

Comment: got it, great! so let's say the same example from the first comment,  ``` pub fn is_empty(&self) -> bool { let head = self.head.load(Ordering::Relaxed); let tail = self.tail.load(Ordering::Relaxed); tail == head} ```, now I change the memory order into relaxed, then now we are not sure the execution order, right? With Relaxed, in the same thread, load tail might happen before head, right?